Download files remotely in Windows terminal
I wish to run download.bat in Window terminal to execute a file named "download.bat" to download files in a folder in university computing cluster (Linux) account to my local directory.
Given that the downloading may interrupt from time to time for unknow reasons, I want the "download.bat" to check for each file in HPC to be downloaded whether it already exists in my local directory. If it exists, print "File *** already exists in F:/GeneResource", where *** is the file name. If the file does not exist in local directory, then download the file.
Caveat:
There is a caveat to note. As the number of files in the local directory increases during file downloading, checking if a file in HPC exists in local directory would take increasingly longer time. I have one suggestion for speeding up. When a file is downloaded to local directory, it exists in the same parent directory as its parent directory in HPC, so the checking only needs to be performed in the immediate subfolder where the file exists. For example, the to check if the file /storage/myLab/sharedata/LDSC_resource/LDSC_SEG_ldscores/Corces_ATAC.ldcts exists in local directory, only need to check in the folder F:/GeneResource/LDSC_resource/LDSC_SEG_ldscores. It is unnecessary to check other subfolders. So the path of the folder in local directory used for checking should be the path of the file in HPC with "/storage/myLab/sharedata/" replaced by "F:/GeneResource/". This reduces unnecessary checking and so will save some time. If you have other clever ideas to speed up, thank you!
The following script is produced by Gemini, which when executed, returned "All downloads completed." even when previous download has been incomplete. Please help me update this code, or write a new one if this script is totally unusable, to implement the functionality while addressing the caveat.
@echo off

rem Define the HPC source directory (Everything in this folder needs to be downloaded)
set HPC_SOURCE=\\storage\myLab\sharedata\LDSC_resource

rem Define the local target directory (All files will be downloaded into this local directory)
set LOCAL_TARGET=F:\GeneResource

rem Loop through each file in the HPC source directory recursively
for /r "%HPC_SOURCE%" %%a in (*) do (
  rem Extract the relative path of the file within the source directory
  set FILE_PATH=%%~na
  
  rem Construct the corresponding local directory path
  set LOCAL_DIR=%LOCAL_TARGET%\!FILE_PATH:\storage\myLab\sharedata\%!
  
  rem Check if the file already exists in the local directory
  if exist "!LOCAL_DIR!" (
    echo File "!FILE_PATH!" already exists in %LOCAL_DIR%
  ) else (
    rem Download the file if it doesn't exist locally
    scp me@172.16.78.132:"!HPC_SOURCE%\!FILE_PATH!" "!LOCAL_DIR!"
    echo Downloaded "!FILE_PATH!" to %LOCAL_DIR%
  )
)

echo All downloads completed.

pause

Please note that the above script is to be written into the "download.bat" file to be run in Windows terminal, not Linux.

Sorry, I deleted that tag.

The command echo All downloads completed. is nothing but a message which is always printed to the console window irrespective of the status of one or more downloads. It is always displayed upon completion of the previous for /r loop.

File *** already exists is never orinted. The only output in terminal is All downloads completed. Press any key to continue . . .". Then, when I press a key, the program is terminated. Something must be wrong with the xurrent version of the code suggested by Maldroid.

You should be running a command that can mirror the remote and local directory structures.  In Windows that is Robocopy.  In Linux that would be rysnc.  I am not clear on whether your remote source is a linux server or if it is a Windows Server running ssh. Or is your Linux server running an SMB share?

It doesn't make any sense that you are using a FOR /R command to iterate the remote source directory but then using scp to copy the file.
